# Calling an async Api call that takes in the returned promise from another Async api call

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to use the data that `loadsummoner` sets into a state that will hold the json object returned but when trying to call the second function I am getting `undefined` when making my api call but on the next render it populates the state that the second function updates.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    try {
      if (Object.keys(results).length === 0) {
        loadSummonerData();
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    return function cleanup() {
      setResults({});
    };
  }, []);

   useEffect( async() => {
    try {
      if (Object.keys(results).length != 0) {
        await setStats(results.id)
    }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error");
    }
    return function cleanup() {
       setStats({});
    };
   }, [results]);
```

I have tried a few different ways to accomplish this like placing the first function call in the second function declaration with await but still reaching an `undefined` state on mount

The function `setStats` should take in an id from a json object contained in the state set by the `loadSummonerData` function.

Answer (score 0):

put everything in the first function call made in the first useeffect!

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy. @AverageDood96

Answer (score 0):

Do not set an async function in useEffect!

instead of `useEffect( async() => {...`, try replace with

```
useEffect(()=> {

(async() => {
    try {
      if (Object.keys(results).length != 0) {
        await setStats(results.id)
    }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error");
    })()

    return function cleanup() {
       setStats({});
    };
   }, [results]);
```